# A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I using asp.net vnext and ef7 when i want adding user i getting this error:

> A relational store has been configured without specifying either the
>   DbConnection or connection string to use.

What is this?

Consider my app start:

```
using DomainModels;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing;
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Presentation.DataAccessLayer.Context;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
namespace Presentation
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = new Configuration()
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationContext, ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseMvc(
                routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
                });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my config.json:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "Connectionstring": "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CraftCenter;Integrated Security=True;"
        }
    },
    "EntityFramework": {
        "ApplicationDbContext": {
            "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem was that your DbContext class name is not the same as the name specified in your config.

For example if you have a DbContext called `MembershipDbContext` you can specify the connection string it should use via the properties inside `EntityFramework`.

```
{
"Data": {
    "Membership": {
        "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Membership;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
},
"EntityFramework": {
    "MembershipDbContext": {
        "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:Membership:ConnectionString"
    }
}
```

This is cleaner than specifying the connection string keys within the code.

In your case, the DbContext name is `ApplicationContext` and the name you've specified in the config is `ApplicationDbContext` which do not match.

Comment: This. Pure genius, I hadn't even noticed the name matched the context, and since I'd moved it (the context) to another dll and renamed it this was my missing link. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
"EntityFramework": {
    "MembershipDbContext": {
        "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:Membership:ConnectionString"
    }
}
```

Changing `ConnectionStringKey` to be `ConnectionString` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to configure the store in the Setup class:

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString")));
     services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationContext, ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(Configuration);
     services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this work without any change since it's defined in the config.json file?

Comment: I would prefer to use this method compared to the accepted answer as it leaves the configuration in the Startup class, I am however getting an error message that this is not available in "ASP.NET Core 5.0". (application works fine without, but scaffolding is barking at me for not "specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use")

Answer (score 1):

I get it and add this code in my context:

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If this is in the context class, the Startup isn't a static class.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as Shawn where this is not a static class

Comment: Did you get a clean solution for this at all? Having the same issue while adding a DbContext to a seperate project in the solution.

Comment: @aredkid's answer below is much preferable, leaving the config in the web project and out of the context specifically. I had also moved the DbContext to a different assembly and renamed it and never noticed that the config.json file is trying to match it up by name (probably to support multiple-context scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for the connection string in DbContext, so you'll need to change "ConnectionStringKey" to "ConnectionString" in the config.json.