# Asp.Net MVC 6 - A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am running the EF migrations from the command prompt.

I am getting the error message as "system.invalidoperationexception: A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use.

I am following on **[View components and Inject in ASP.NET MVC 6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#cnp)**

Run EF migrations

In an administrator command window, change the directory to the project directory. The project directory contains the project.json file.
In a command prompt, run the following:

```
k ef migration add initial 
k ef migration apply
```

Comment: Is your DbContext in a different project than your Startup class?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677834/a-relational-store-has-been-configured-without-specifying-either-the-dbconnectio/28638219#28638219

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this similar question and ensure that your [config file has the connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28638219/148802).

Also, I noticed this error in beta3 during migration only, and updated the `OnConfiguring` method in my DbContext to specify the connection string as well.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
{
        options.UseInMemoryStore("Data:DbContextName:ConnectionString");
}
```

Comment: I'm using UseSqlServer, and I cannot specify just the config key. It requires the actual connection string.